# How to specify the Android API version by adding in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, ibm-mobilefirst

After creating a mobile-first Cordova project with the command:

```
cordova create cordovatest1 com.sample.cordova cordovatest1 --template cordova-template-mfp
```

I add the Android platform to the project with the command:

```
cordova platform add android
```

the question is why the Android version for the platform which was just added takes the Android API 23 / android version 5.1.1, even I have already other API levels: 22, 25, 27 in SDK manager?

is there a config file belong to Cordova says that the Android platform must be for example android-23 if the developer didn't specify the Android version by adding like

```
cordova platform add android@6.1.2
```

or maybe the mobilefirst-cli witch is already installed under the version 8.0.0 force that adding platforms?

This screenshot can give you more details

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unrelated to IBM MobileFirstPlatform SDK plugin. The Android target is determined by your Cordova version.

For example, cordova-android@6.1.2 targets Android API Level 25.
cordova-android@6.3.0 targets Android API Level 26.

Details [here](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/09/27/android-release.html).

You have not mentioned your Cordova CLI version. Since you see cordova-android@5.1.1 being added, it seems to be [Cordova CLI version 6.0](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2016/03/02/cordova-android-5.1.1.html).

The results would be the same if you were to create a blank Cordova project ( without cordova-template-mfp) and then add platform.

Comment: Where i can changed if it's related to Cordova version, thanks

Comment: You can mention it specifically when adding the platform:
cordova platform add android@6.3.0 or cordova platform add android@6.1.2

Comment: you didn't understand what I mean, I don't want to add the Android platform version explicitly, the question is, why when we run the cmd for adding the Android platform to cordova base project we got the andoird verson 5.1.1 and not 6.1.2

Comment: I do not think you understood the explanation. The default version of Android is determined by the version of Cordova CLI you have installed. Upgrade your Cordova CLI if you want a higher version of cordova-android added by default

Comment: Because you have saved Android 5.1.1 in npm-cache.

Check npm-cache folder: C:\Users\Training\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\cordova-android

Answer (score 1):

> why the Android version for the platform which was just added takes
>   the Android API 23 / android version 5.1.1

Because you have saved Android 5.1.1 in **npm-cache**.

Check npm-cache folder:
[C:\Users\Training\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\cordova-android](http://C:%5CUsers%5CTraining%5CAppData%5CRoaming%5Cnpm-cache%5Ccordova-android)

Currently the Cordova android platform versions supported by the MobileFirst plug-ins, is:

**cordova-android: >= 6.1.2 and < 9.0**

Try using these command:

**To upgrade:**

```
cordova platform update android@9.0
```

**To add it explicitly:**

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android@9.0
```

or

```
cordova platform add android@latest
```

**For more details see here :** https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/sdk/cordova/

Comment: Now with latest ifix onwards  MobileFirst Plugins support Cordova 8 and Cordova Android 7 as well.More details see here 
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2018/04/09/8-0-ifix-release/